# Eloquent Query, possible Join

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three models: driver, designation and dpsObject, with the following replationships:

driver->hasMany(dpsObject)
driver->belongsTo(Designation)

designation->hasMany(Driver)

dpsObject->belongsTo(Driver)

I'm trying to write a query to return a list of dpsObject records that correspond to the values of three user inputs, which are: a date range(From and To) holding the values of an EntryDate field in the dpsObject and a Designation input, holding the value of a Designation_name field in the Designation object.
Currently this is my Query:

```
$dps = dpsObject::where([['entryDate', '>=', $from],
                              ['entryDate', '<=', $to]]);
```

$from and $to hold the request values gotten from the form user's submit. 
I need to complete the query to capture the Designation name of a driver that that has dpsObject records. The challenge is that the designation_name field does not exist on the dpsObject model but only on the driver and designation models. This is how I want to maintain the database model. I think I need to be using a join or something similar, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

What is the best way to write such a query?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `whereHas()`:

```
$dpsObjects = dpsObject::whereBetween('entryDate', [$from, $to])
    ->whereHas('driver', function ($q) use($designationName) {
        $q->whereHas('designation', function ($q) use($designationName) {
            $q->where('designation_name', $designationName);
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

Here, `designation` and `driver` are `belongsTo()` relationships.

Comment: @Alexy this is the error I'm getting. 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' (SQL: select * from `dps_objects` where `entryDate` between 2017-07-01 and 2017-07-01 and exists (select * from `drivers` where `dps_objects`.`driver_no` = `drivers`.`driver_no` and exists (select * from `designations` where `drivers`.`designation_name` = `designations`.`designation_name` and `designation_name` = Total)))

does this have to do with how the relationships are setup?